# I have 28 errors, this is my first program, h elp out if you can

Tags: java

I'm trying to make some sort of a primitive form on what I'd optimize to be an interactive BMI calculator I guess.
So this is my code.

CODE:

import java.util.Scanner;

class bmi{

public static void main(String args[]) {

```
Scanner userinput = new Scanner(System.in);

double weight, height, bmi;
String sex;

System.out.println("Hello there!");

System.out.println("I am your Body-Mass index calculator!");

System.out.println("Would you please be so kind and tell me your weight? In kilograms if possible, I'm from Europe xD.");
weight = userinput.nextDouble();

System.out.println("Alrighty, now tell me, how tall are you? In meters this time.");
height = userinput.nextDouble();

System.out.println("Finally, can you tell me wether you are a boy or a girl, if that isn't too intrusive... *wink*");
sex = userinput.nextLine();

bmi = weight / (height * height);

if (sex = "boy")  {
    System.out.println("Thank you for providing me this information, bro!");
    System.out.println("                                    ");
    System.out.println("Hmm, it looks like your results came...");
}
else {
    System.out.println("Thanks for the indormation, sys! ;)");
    System.out.println("                                    ");
    System.out.println("Hmm, it looks like your results came...");
}

   System.out.println("                                           ");

   if (bmi <= 18.5 && sex = "boy")  {
       System.out.println("Looking just at your height and weight, I can tell you are a skinny guy, in fact the data (your BMI is "bmi") shows that you are underweight. You might consider gaining some wight, it would be best for your health.");

   }
   else if (bmi <= 25 && sex = "boy")  {
       System.out.println("Damn son, you're looking good (in numbers xD)! With a BMI of "bmi", you are just about average, nothing to worry about here!);

   }
   else if (bmi <= 18.5 && sex = "girl")  {
       System.out.println("Looking at the numbers you gave me, it seems that you are underweight :/, in fact with a bmi of "bmi",your weight is below that of an average girl. Not having considered your age, there is no way I can tell you wether the condition is critical or not, but you should really consider gaining some weight.");

   }
   else if (bmi <= 25 && sex = "girl")  {
       System.out.println("Damn giiiirl, you rock! Having a BMI of "bmi", you are an ideal specimen of a healthy female figure. Keep it up!);

   }
   else if (bmi > 25 && sex = "girl")  {
       System.out.println("First of all, let me say it's not critical, but with a BMI of "bmi", you are considered overweight, try working out or going for a run from time to time, it sure will help your health.);

   }
   else if (bmi > 25 && sex = "boy")  {
       System.out.println("First of all, let me say it's not critical, but with a BMI of "bmi", you are considered overweight, try working out or going for a run from time to time, it sure will help your health.);   

   } 
   else if (bmi > 30) then {
       System.out.println("I am so sorry to be the one to inform you, but with a BMI of "bmi",you are consiered obese by the National Health Orgnaization, at this point, your weight might be seriously affecting your health, and I strongly suggest you to take on a diet, start working out or if the case is extreme, seek professional help. Do it for yourself, I believe in you! <3");
   }

   System.out.println("                                           ");
   System.out.println("Thank you for letting me help!");
```

}

}

OK, and now here is the report:

javac JavaTutorial.java

JavaTutorial.java:39: error: ')' expected

```
       System.out.println("Looking just at your height and weight, I can tell you are a skinny guy, in fact the data (your BMI is "bmi") shows that you are underweight. You might consider gaining some wight, it would be best for your health.");

                                                                                                                                   ^
```

JavaTutorial.java:39: error: not a statement

```
       System.out.println("Looking just at your height and weight, I can tell you are a skinny guy, in fact the data (your BMI is "bmi") shows that you are underweight. You might consider gaining some wight, it would be best for your health.");

                                                                                                                                      ^
```

JavaTutorial.java:39: error: ';' expected

```
       System.out.println("Looking just at your height and weight, I can tell you are a skinny guy, in fact the data (your BMI is "bmi") shows that you are underweight. You might consider gaining some wight, it would be best for your health.");

                                                                                                                                                                                                                        ^
```

JavaTutorial.java:43: error: ')' expected

```
       System.out.println("Damn son, you're looking good (in numbers xD)! With a BMI of "bmi", you are just about average, nothing to worry about here!);

                                                        ^
```

JavaTutorial.java:43: error: unclosed string literal

```
       System.out.println("Damn son, you're looking good (in numbers xD)! With a BMI of "bmi", you are just about average, nothing to worry about here!);

                                                                                            ^
```

JavaTutorial.java:43: error: ';' expected

System.out.println("Damn son, you're looking good (in numbers xD)! With a BMI of "bmi", you are just about average, nothing to worry about here!);

```
                                                                                                                                                         ^
```

JavaTutorial.java:47: error: ')' expected

System.out.println("Looking at the numbers you gave me, it seems that you are underweight :/, in fact with a bmi of "bmi",your weight is below that of an average girl. Not having considered your age, there is no way I can tell you wether the condition is critical or not, but you should really consider gaining some weight.");

```
                                                                                                                            ^
```

JavaTutorial.java:47: error: not a statement

System.out.println("Looking at the numbers you gave me, it seems that you are underweight :/, in fact with a bmi of "bmi",your weight is below that of an average girl. Not having considered your age, there is no way I can tell you wether the condition is critical or not, but you should really consider gaining some weight.");

```
                                                                                                                               ^
```

JavaTutorial.java:47: error: ';' expected

System.out.println("Looking at the numbers you gave me, it seems that you are underweight :/, in fact with a bmi of "bmi",your weight is below that of an average girl. Not having considered your age, there is no way I can tell you wether the condition is critical or not, but you should really consider gaining some weight.");

```
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           ^
```

JavaTutorial.java:51: error: ')' expected

System.out.println("Damn giiiirl, you rock! Having a BMI of "bmi", you are an ideal specimen of a healthy female figure. Keep it up!);

```
                                                                    ^
```

JavaTutorial.java:51: error: unclosed string literal

System.out.println("Damn giiiirl, you rock! Having a BMI of "bmi", you are an ideal specimen of a healthy female figure. Keep it up!);
                                                                           ^
JavaTutorial.java:51: error: ';' expected

System.out.println("Damn giiiirl, you rock! Having a BMI of "bmi", you are an ideal specimen of a healthy female figure. Keep it up!);
                                                                                                                                                 ^
JavaTutorial.java:55: error: ')' expected

System.out.println("First of all, let me say it's not critical, but with a BMI of "bmi", you are considered overweight, try working out or going for a run from time to time, it sure will help your health.);

```
                                                                                          ^
```

JavaTutorial.java:55: error: unclosed string literal

System.out.println("First of all, let me say it's not critical, but with a BMI of "bmi", you are considered overweight, try working out or going for a run from time to time, it sure will help your health.);
                                                                                                 ^
JavaTutorial.java:55: error: ';' expected

System.out.println("First of all, let me say it's not critical, but with a BMI of "bmi", you are considered overweight, try working out or going for a run from time to time, it sure will help your health.);
                                                                                                                                                                                                                         ^
JavaTutorial.java:59: error: ')' expected

System.out.println("First of all, let me say it's not critical, but with a BMI of "bmi", you are considered overweight, try working out or going for a run from time to time, it sure will help your health.);
                                                                                              ^
JavaTutorial.java:59: error: unclosed string literal

System.out.println("First of all, let me say it's not critical, but with a BMI of "bmi", you are considered overweight, try working out or going for a run from time to time, it sure will help your health.);
                                                                                                 ^
JavaTutorial.java:59: error: ';' expected

System.out.println("First of all, let me say it's not critical, but with a BMI of "bmi", you are considered overweight, try working out or going for a run from time to time, it sure will help your health.);

```
                                                                                                                                                                      ^
```

JavaTutorial.java:62: error: not a statement

```
   else if (bmi > 30) then {

                      ^
```

JavaTutorial.java:62: error: ';' expected

else if (bmi > 30) then {
                              ^
JavaTutorial.java:62: error: 'else' without 'if'

else if (bmi > 30) then {
       ^

JavaTutorial.java:63: error: ')' expected

System.out.println("I am so sorry to be the one to inform you, but with a BMI of "bmi",you are consiered obese by the National Health Orgnaization, at this point, your weight might be seriously affecting your health, and I strongly suggest you to take on a diet, start working out or if the case is extreme, seek professional help. Do it for yourself, I believe in you! <3");
                                                                                             ^
JavaTutorial.java:63: error: not a statement

System.out.println("I am so sorry to be the one to inform you, but with a BMI of "bmi",you are consiered obese by the National Health Orgnaization, at this point, your weight might be seriously affecting your health, and I strongly suggest you to take on a diet, start working out or if the case is extreme, seek professional help. Do it for yourself, I believe in you! <3");

```
                                                                                            ^
```

JavaTutorial.java:63: error: ';' expected

System.out.println("I am so sorry to be the one to inform you, but with a BMI of "bmi",you are consiered obese by the National Health Orgnaization, at this point, your weight might be seriously affecting your health, and I strongly suggest you to take on a diet, start working out or if the case is extreme, seek professional help. Do it for yourself, I believe in you! <3");
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                ^
JavaTutorial.java:58: error: 'else' without 'if'

```
   else if (bmi > 25 && sex = "boy")  {


   ^
```

JavaTutorial.java:54: error: 'else' without 'if'

```
   else if (bmi > 25 && sex = "girl")  {


   ^
```

JavaTutorial.java:46: error: reached end of file while parsing

```
   else if (bmi <= 18.5 && sex = "girl")  {


   ^
```

JavaTutorial.java:72: error: reached end of file while parsing

}

^

28 errors

Comment: Consider what is on-topic for this forum: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Looking again at your code, you've got multiple errors, and this suggests that your style of coding perhaps needs to be fixed. Don't type a large amount of code and then test it. Instead if you can't use a modern IDE such as NetBeans or Eclipse (which warns you of compilation issues almost immediately), then it is up to you to compile your code **early and often**, and most importantly **to not add any new code until current compilation issues are fixed**. Else you'll end up with a rat's nest of hard to fix errors.

Comment: I suggest that you start over

Comment: If you have 28 errors and you can't figure out _any_ of them, then you need more help than we can give you.  But I suspect that you just panicked and haven't tried to figure them out yet.  Look at them one at a time.  Start with the first.  Sometimes fixing an error will cause more than one error to go away.

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it for you. There were several mistakes.

1. if comparisons always need two equal signs like this: `if(a == b){...}`
2. There is no `then` in if clauses in java
3. Always comare Strings with the `String.equals` method. A String is saved as an object in java. Comparing two objects with `==` never returns true, unless they are two variables pointing at the same instance. In this case you are comparing the content of an object, which is why you should use `string1.equals(string2)`
4. Idk why, but scanner.nextLine() didn't work, but scanner.next() did. Since you are asking for a single word, this shouldn't cause any problems. I'm not too familiar with `scanner` but it worked for me ;)
5. when trying to insert a variable into a String you need to use plus signs like this: `"something written here " + someVariable + "something written over there"`.

Here is the fixed code:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner userinput = new Scanner(System.in);

        double weight, height, bmi;
        String sex;

        System.out.println("Hello there!");

        System.out.println("I am your Body-Mass index calculator!");

        System.out.println(
            "Would you please be so kind and tell me your weight? In kilograms if possible, I'm from Europe xD.");
        weight = userinput.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("Alrighty, now tell me, how tall are you? In meters this time.");
        height = userinput.nextDouble();

        System.out.println(
            "Finally, can you tell me wether you are a boy or a girl, if that isn't too intrusive... *wink*");
        sex = userinput.nextLine();

        bmi = weight / (height * height);
        if ( sex.equals("boy")) {
            System.out.println("Thank you for providing me this information, bro!");
            System.out.println("                                    ");
            System.out.println("Hmm, it looks like your results came...");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Thanks for the information, sys! ;)");
            System.out.println("                                    ");
            System.out.println("Hmm, it looks like your results came...");
        }

        System.out.println("                                           ");

        if (bmi <= 18.5 && sex.equals("boy")) {
            System.out.println(
                "Looking just at your height and weight, I can tell you are a skinny guy, in fact the data (your BMI is "
                + bmi
                + ") shows that you are underweight. You might consider gaining some wight, it would be best for your health.");

        } else if (bmi <= 25 && sex.equals("boy")) {
            System.out.println("Damn son, you're looking good (in numbers xD)! With a BMI of " + bmi
                + ", you are just about average, nothing to worry about here!");

        } else if (bmi <= 18.5 && sex.equals("girl")) {
            System.out.println(
                "Looking at the numbers you gave me, it seems that you are underweight :/, in fact with a bmi of "
                + bmi
                + ",your weight is below that of an average girl. Not having considered your age, there is no way I can tell you wether the condition is critical or not, but you should really consider gaining some weight.");

        } else if (bmi <= 25 && sex.equals("girl")) {
            System.out.println("Damn giiiirl, you rock! Having a BMI of " + bmi
                + ", you are an ideal specimen of a healthy female figure. Keep it up!");

        } else if (bmi > 25 && sex.equals("girl")) {
            System.out.println("First of all, let me say it's not critical, but with a BMI of " + bmi
                + ", you are considered overweight, try working out or going for a run from time to time, it sure will help your health.");

        } else if (bmi > 25 && sex.equals("boy")) {
            System.out.println("First of all, let me say it's not critical, but with a BMI of " + bmi
                + ", you are considered overweight, try working out or going for a run from time to time, it sure will help your health.");

        } else if (bmi > 30) {
            System.out.println("I am so sorry to be the one to inform you, but with a BMI of " + bmi
                + ",you are consiered obese by the National Health Orgnaization, at this point, your weight might be seriously affecting your health, and I strongly suggest you to take on a diet, start working out or if the case is extreme, seek professional help. Do it for yourself, I believe in you! <3");
        }

        System.out.println("                                           ");
        System.out.println("Thank you for letting me help!");

    }
```

Comment: I would also suggest you look into "switch-case" to make your code prettier